# Can I update a session variable using ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, modal-dialog, bootstrap-form-helper

I'm using laravel 5.1, I want to update a session variable using ajax when I click on a button to show modal dialog which contains a form, so I can bind a model to this form according to this variable,
Here my code :

```
$('#editRole').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {          
        $roleID =  $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');       
        $.ajax({           
            url: "/sessionVars", 
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { editKey : $roleID ,_token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' }
        });                       
    });
```

Controller :

```
public function setSessionVars(Request $request)
  {             
      if(Input::has('editKey')) {          
         Session::put('roleID', $request->input('editKey') ); 
      }          
  }
```

and then, on my modal I do like this :

```
...
               <?php                                         
                    if(Session::has('roleID'))
                    {                       
                        $role = App\Models\Role::find(Session::get('roleID'));
                    }

                ?>
...
                {!! BootForm::open()->action( route('role.edit', $role) )->put() !!}
                {!! BootForm::bind($role) !!}
...
```

Please Help me ..

NB: my problem is I can't update variable value properly ..

Comment: I tried to use config file but not working,
Controller :
`Config::set('vars.editKey', $request->input('editKey'));`

Blade view :
`$roleID = Config::get('vars.editKey');`

Comment: The problem is that the variable is not stored in the session ? Try `Session::save()` just after `Session::put`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :/
I think the modal needs to be refreshed to update value !

Comment: does the code of the modal executes after the `setSessionVars` code? Also: the controller code that sets the variable should end with something like this `return Response::json(['response' => 'ok']);` so the request cycle could end properly

Comment: In fact, my modal is already set via @include('modal') when I click on button and run that code in controller .. so is there a solution for this ? May be I can get the attribute value by php instead of javascript ?

Comment: so you include the last part of the code BEFORE triggering the `setSessionVars` calls? In this case the session variable has not  still being set.

Comment: How can I solve this ? is there a way to get tag value of an attribute using php ? here I do with javascript like this :  $roleID =  $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');

Comment: Probably you should solve this in another way. Please edit the post and try to explain what are you triyng to do and what is your purpose